# replace all links in text by Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

i want replace all links in text With the exception of images Links

```
$text = '<p>
<a href="http://msn.com" rel="attachment wp-att-7046"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-7046" alt="geak-eye-mars" src="http://google/2013/06/geak-eye-mars.jpg" width="619" height="414" /></a></p>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
<p><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">any word</a>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
</p>';
```

i want replace `(http://msn.com and http://google.com)` and other links , but links of images like this `(http://google/2013/06/geak-eye-mars.jpg)` Remain as it is ..
i hope u understand me .. i want only replace all links Between this tag

```
href="Link"
```

by this code

```
$text = ereg_replace("all links","another link">",$text);
```

Thank you

Comment: why dont u try with a str_replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DOM to do this:

```
$text = <<<LOD
<p><a href="http://msn.com" rel="attachment wp-att-7046">
<img  src="http://google/2013/06/geak-eye-mars.jpg" /></a></p>
  bla bla bla bla bla bla
<p><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">any word</a>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
</p>
LOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($text);
$aNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($aNodes as $aNode) {
    $href = $aNode->getAttribute("href");
    $new_href = '!!!Youhou!!! '. $href;
    $aNode->setAttribute("href", $new_href);
}

$new_text = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: thnx that's worked good But there is a problem in the charset , Is it possible to be solved by iconv()

Comment: @o6qr: take a look at the first comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: okay , but same problem $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8">' . $text);

Comment: @o6qr: You must deal with the charset of your html document, code editor, wordpress configuration, server configuration, loadHTML, to solve the problem. Good luck! Perhaps your html document isn't encoded with utf8, try to replace it with ISO8859-??

Comment: yes every thing is utf-8 , and my file is utf without bom .. any way thnx very much

Comment: $doc = new DOMDocument();
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
@$doc->loadHTML($text);

Answer (score 0):

If you want a permanent solution that won't break, use a DOM parser, like the other answers suggest. Using regular expressions to parse html is a really bad idea.

However, if you just want a one-time, quick solution, something like this will do:

```
preg_replace('/(href=["\']?)[^"\']+/', '$1' . $newtext, $html);
```

Guaranteed, this will fail on some html files (like if the URL is not wrapped in quotes), but it will work with most as long as the person who wrote the html file used best practices. Don't use this in production code. Ever.

Comment: thnx but not worked , i think ur code wrong (u put dot befor $newtext) must be like  preg_replace('/(href=["\']?)[^"\']+/', '$1' , $newtext);

Comment: Actually, the period is intentional. That puts $1 at the front of the replacement so that href= doesnt get removed. The mistake I made was forgetting to add the subject parameter. Edited the answer. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = <<<LOD
<p><a href="http://msn.com" rel="attachment wp-att-7046">
<img  src="http://google/2013/06/geak-eye-mars.jpg" /></a></p>
  bla bla bla bla bla bla
<p><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">any word</a>
bla bla bla bla bla bla
</p>
LOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
@$doc->loadHTML($text);
$aNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($aNodes as $aNode) {
    $href = $aNode->getAttribute("href");
    $new_href = '!!!Youhou!!! '. $href;
    $aNode->setAttribute("href", $new_href);
}

$new_text = $doc->saveHTML();
```